# error to reloading page polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I created different pages with neon-animated-pages.

So when I use href to go to the page it's works, but when I try to reload the page, I have a 404 error.

This is my app.html

```
<app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path></app-location>
    <app-route
            route="{{route}}"
            pattern="/:view"
            data="{{routeData}}"
            tail="{{subroute}}">
    </app-route>
    <div class="container flex-vertical">
        <app-header id="header">
            <neon-animated-pages selected="[[routeData.view]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallbackSelection="home" class="fit" selected-attribute="reload">
                <app-home-page name="" route="{{subroute}}"></app-home-page>
                <app-profil-page name="profil" route="{{subroute}}"></app-profil-page>
                <app-setting-page name="settings" route="{{subroute}}"></app-setting-page>
            </neon-animated-pages>
        </app-header>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up your `.htaccess` file. For example mine is

```
<filesMatch "\.(js)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L]
```

`filesMatch` rule is not important for you, so you can skip it. I just needed to prevent caching some files on the server side.

`.htaccess` redirects all routes to `index.html` or whatever path you choose. And then `app-route` will handle routing even after refresh